# Push to 2D Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, each

I am trying to understand how 2D Arrays should work in Javascript, where I am currently attempting to store data in categories. In this scenario, I have a list of maps such as...

```
arena_badlands
arena_dust
ctf_2fort
cp_dustbowl
```

I would like to create a 2D Array where they are categorized by the types (arena, ctf, cp) so I can handle the data more efficiently. For whatever reason, I am unable to use the `push()` method as expected. Can anyone please help share what it is that I am doing incorrectly?

As the maps in the list won't necessarily be in order by type, it keeps me from creating a single array of arena maps and then placing this inside of availableMaps.

```
var availableMaps = [[]];       // Store all maps on the server which can be loaded

function getMaps()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "handler.php",
        data: { 'action': 'getMaps' },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            var maps = data['maps'];
            var counter = 0;

            $.each( maps, function( key, value )
            {
                // Split map name to fetch the type (ex: arena_badlands would be an 'arena' map)
                var parts = value.split("_");
                var mapType = parts[0];

                availableMaps[mapType][counter].push(value);

                counter++;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How are the categories determined?  By the name before the underscore?

Comment: Two dimensional arrays have two numeric indexes.  You probably want an object with properties pointing to arrays: `var obj = {  category1: [], category2: []  }`  then you can access like so: `obj['category2'][index]`

Comment: When you do `availableMaps[mapType][counter].push(value);`, you are trying to create a third dimension. `availableMaps[mapType].push(value);` will do the way you want, but you can't store values by index. The counter is also redundant, since pushing a new value into an array will store it by it's index. As SaraBourt pointed out, if you want to store by a key, you want an object.

Comment: In JavaScript there is no `associative arrays`, instead you should use object `{}`, like so http://jsfiddle.net/5e1yehfu/

Comment: @James that is correct. Coming from PHP, I didn't realize that Javascript couldn't have non numeric indexes. Should I do an array of objects or an object containing arrays in this case? Being able to store it as availableMaps['arena'][0] = "arena_badlands", availableMaps['arena'][1] = "arena_dust" is what I am going for.

Comment: You also need to keep in mind that your availableMaps array is blank. So when you call availableMaps[mapType], you're actually getting undefined back.

Comment: Actually, JavaScript CAN have non-numeric indexes.  The length property doesn't increase, but you can have named indexes.

Comment: For my own sanity, I went ahead and just made it a 2d associative array in PHP via the AJAX Handler and passed it back that way which JS turned into an object for me. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
var inputs = ["arena_badlands", "arena_dust", "ctf_2fort", "cp_dustbowl"];

function getAvailableMaps(inputs) {
    var map = {}, parts, name, item, items;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
        parts = inputs[i].split('_');
        name = parts[0];
        item = parts.slice(1).join("");
        items = map[name] || (map[name] = []);
        items.push(item);
    }
    return map;
}

var availableMaps = getAvailableMaps(inputs);
```

It creates an object at the root for holding named indexes, and uses an array to store the list of items.

Here is another approach as well:

```
var inputs = ["arena_badlands", "arena_dust", "ctf_2fort", "cp_dustbowl"];

function getAvailableMaps(inputs) {
    var map = {}, input, name, item, items;
    for (var i = 0, i2; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
        input = inputs[i];
        i2 = input.indexOf("_");
        if (i2 == -1) continue; // (or throw an error)
        name = input.substring(0, i2);
        item = input.substring(i2+1);
        items = map[name] || (map[name] = []);
        items.push(item);
    }
    return map;
}

var availableMaps = getAvailableMaps(inputs);
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks like a good approach to accomplish the task, I appreciate it :)